# Adding python directory

Tags: microsoft-windows, plugin-system, error, python

After following some advice my `vimrc` contains:

```
set rnu
set nu
set autoindent
set pythonthreedll=C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim82\autoload\python37.dll
set pythonthreehome=C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim82\autoload
set noerrorbells
set colorcolumn=80
set tabstop=2
set bg=light
colorscheme elflord
set guifont=Courier:h14
set spelllang=en,en_us
set spell
call plug#begin()
Plug 'junegunn/vim-plug'
Plug 'lervag/vimtex'
Plug 'ycm-core/YouCompleteMe'
Plug 'python-mode/python-mode'
call plug#end()
let g:tex_flavor = 'latex'
```

However I get these errors:

```
Error detected while processing C:\Users\maria\vimfiles\vimrc:

line    4:
E518: Unknown option: Files 

line    5:
E518: Unknown option: Files
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must escape spaces in directory names using a backslash. Also note that "autoload" subdirectory is not a proper place to put your python files.

Comment: should it be ````C:\Program\Files\(x86)\Vim\vim82\autoload\python37.dll````  how will the computer know I don't mean ````C ->Program->Files->(x86)->....````

Comment: @user716881 "escape space" means "add backslash before space"

Comment: Oh so like ````C:\Program\ Files\ (x86)\Vim\vim82\autoload\python37.dll````

Comment: where should I put my python files if not in my autoload

Comment: @user716881 Your Python installation should be outside the Vim installation, these are two separate programs, so it doesn't really make much sense to install one inside another. Try `C:\Program Files (x86)\Python` or similar. Furthermore, the `autoload` directory in Vim has a very specific purpose, which is to store `*.vim` files from where functions can be loaded on demand based on the function names. You shouldn't really store DLLs or other files there not related to this purpose.